# Telling django which db template to use

Tags: django, postgresql, postgis, geodjango

How can i tell django/geodjango which database template to use for creating test runner database?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://code.djangoproject.com/browser/django/trunk/django/contrib/gis/db/backends/postgis/creation.py#L58